# How can I save my game after beating Ganon in Twilight Princess?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

I just beat/finished *The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess*. I stepped out of the room while the credits were playing. When I came back, the title screen was showing. Did I miss my chance to save?  How do I save my game after beating Ganon?

Comment: In MM it saves and sends you back to the first of the 3 days, you can carry on through the game with everything you have, you can do all the dungeons and whatever as much as you like..also in Wind Waker it tells you to save but in a new slot so because once you finish it starts the game again, but you have the colour pictobox right from the start, you also get a little thing showing you have completed the game at the main menu =]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say... you... don't? I can't remember clearly, but I'm fairly certain the best you can do is save before Ganon.

Comment: This seems to be true of all Zelda games. After beating the last boss you have *effectively* completed the game. Yes, you can still keep playing to find those last few treasures etc. but you have to do it from a point just before the last boss dungeon.

Comment: How does MM factor into this? I know that you still cannot save, but the game does somehow save your Deity's Mask if you get it.

Comment: @Mike Webb: The Fierce Diety mask is gained by getting every other mask in the game *except* Majora's Mask.  In other words, you'll have the Fierce Diety's Mask before reaching the moon.

Comment: A number of Zelda games have you save after completing them... examples are Zelda 1 (because it has a second quest), Oracle of Ages/Oracle of Seasons (because of the linked games), and. as Sam pointed out. Wind Waker.

Comment: @Powerlord not exactly, you obtain the Firece Deity mask _on_ the moon, but you can _then_ play the tune of time to save having obtained it.

Comment: @Mike I think you saved that by playing the tune of time _before_ fighting the mask

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler - Actually no. I have beaten the game twice so far with the Deity mask and every time I get to the moon, give up my masks and get through the dungeons, and the kid alone by the tree gives me the deity mask. I then proceed to beat Majora's Mask with the deity mask and watch the final movie. When there is nothing left to do I reset the game. When I start my game again I am before the moon on the first day and have the deity mask.

Comment: @Mike oh, I didn't test that. So I skipped back to day one once more than necessary... Thanks for telling

Answer (score 15):

Not every game lets you save after the final boss or has a "New Game+" mode. Twilight Princess is one of these.

After you beat Ganon, there's nothing else - you're done. You've beaten the game. Nothing comes after, so there's no reason you need to *save* after.

If you want to go back and collect heart containers (or whatever else), you'll have to manually trudge out of Ganon's castle to get them.

Zelda may have been one of the first to use the concept of a NewGame+ (With the original LoZ's 2nd Quest), but not every game has them. Ocarina of Time and Twilight Princess, for instance, don't. Windwaker and Skyward Sword, do. It just varies by game.

Answer (score 2):

You can't save. I know it sucks, but it doesn't matter since all you can do is do the Cave of Ordeals.

Answer (score 0):

after you beat ganon it goes to your last save point but it stays night time so if you want to do the malo mart side quests you need to do it before you best the second last dungeon cause from that point on it stays night

Answer (score 0):

I've beating the game many times and realized there is no time to save the game. However you can save after getting the boss key in Hyrule Castle, that way every time you redo it you can just walkthrough the castle. But look on the bright side, you beat the game!!!