# Why can't I save my game after I beat Ganon in Twilight Princess?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I save my game after beating Ganon in Twilight Princess?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/how-can-i-save-my-game-after-beating-ganon-in-twilight-princess)

See, I fought him in all four stages, and in the last one I saved my game to make sure. After I beat him, the credits staring rolling, and I stayed and watched all of the credits and there was no time in the credits or after where I could save. So I thought the game had just automatically saved for me. But when I went back on the game a few hours later, I was right back at the castle to fight Ganon and I still had Midna. Any idea of where to save or why this might have happened?